# Pinescript Indicator to alert Crossing Up or Crossing Down

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create an indicator to fire alert whenever it is crossing Down or crossing Up a specific price.

Can anyone help me to create an indicator to fire alert whenever it is crossing down 23000 and crossing up 22000 please. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to write code for that if that's the only thing you want. You can do it via the alert settings.

[image]

If you want to write your own code for it, you can use `ta.crossover()` or `ta.crossunder()` functions.

```
target_price = 100
cross_up = ta.crossover(close, target_price)
cross_down = ta.crossunder(close, target_price)

alertcondition(cross_up, "Cross up")
alertcondition(cross_down , "Cross down")
```

Comment: Thank you Vitruvius. Please continue to be here in stackoverflow as you are one of the trusted pine programmers and pinescript guru. I appreciate your time and commitment towards us. Thankyou so much.